# How do I provide credentials to the docker awslogs driver using Docker for Mac?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to use the docker [awslogs driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/awslogs/) and getting the following error:

> "docker: Error response from daemon: Failed to initialize logging
>   driver: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain.
>   Deprecated."

According to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19392#issuecomment-221654053), I need to set the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable for the docker daemon, but I'm not sure how to do that when using Docker for Mac.

The command I'm using to start the container is:

```
docker run -d \
 --log-driver=awslogs \
 --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 \
 --log-opt awslogs-group=my-log-group \
 my-image
```

Version information:

- Docker for Mac 1.12.1-rc1-beta23 build 11375
- OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: What command do you use to start your docker container?

Comment: @tokeryberg, edited my question to add the command.

Comment: Out of curiousity- why would you want the logs from your laptop sent to aws?

Comment: It's not a laptop, it's a Mac Mini running as a production server. To answer your follow-up question, the reasons we are using a Mac Mini as a production server are historical / out of necessity. Hopefully we will switch to Ubuntu as the host OS soon, but who knows when that will happen.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/nearform/docker-cloudwatch, which has been working well.

Answer (score 1):

> but I'm not sure how to do that when using Docker for Mac.

With [boot2docker](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/), you would need to modify `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` in order to add this variable.
See "[Docker daemon config file on boot2docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26424338/6309)".
It does persists across the TinyCore-based VM reboot, and the docker daemon would then take it into account.

With the new [docker for Mac xhyve-based](http://www.docker.com/products/docker#/mac), the idea should be the same.
`/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` does exist as well, as shown [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/792683/783).
The official [docker dameon doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) points to:

```
--config-file=/etc/docker/daemon.json  Daemon configuration file
```

So try and modify this file.

By default, the comments mention:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.doc‌​ker.driver.amd64-lin‌​ux/etc/docker/daemon‌​.json
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. `/var/lib/boot2docker/` didn't exist (I'm using Docker 1.12.1-rc1-beta23 build 11375), so I created it and a profile file, exported AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE in it, and restarted docker, but I got the same error.

Comment: @MikeOttum But you are using Docker for Mac, right? I don't remember if that new xhyve version is using boot2docker or not, but if the folder boot2docker does not exist... I suppose not. In that case, try and look at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`: IT might reference an Environmentfile which you could modify and add your EXPORT.

Comment: that's correct, I'm using Docker for Mac on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6. `/usr/lib/systemd` doesn't exist on my system. I did a `find / | grep docker.service` and it came up empty. :-/

Comment: @MikeOttum and `find / |grep docker`?

Comment: `find / | grep docker` outputs this: https://gist.github.com/ottumm/6b8bf4e9abc6faed14008fa61d2e7f31

Comment: @MikeOttum OK, you output is consistent with a regular docker installation. I have edited my answer. (although https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21559 is an interesting read)

Comment: @mik I see it didn't work, I presume? (Since the answer is dowvoted)

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. But, no, it didn't work because `/etc/docker` doesn't exist on Docker for Mac. I appreciate all the effort on this, though. I think it's likely that I'm going to give up on using the awslogs driver for now and try a different solution until I can move to Linux.

Comment: @MikeOttum I found mine in: `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker/daemon.json`

Answer (score 0):

Using information taken from this answer: [Docker deamon config path under mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785991/docker-deamon-config-path-under-mac-os)

You can connect to the VM layer that runs the docker daemon using:

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

And you can modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to add the needed variables there.

Once you make your changes, you can just run:

```
service docker restart
```

from within the moby terminal to restart the docker daemon.

Do notice that if you restart docker from your mac, the changes will not persist.

On a side note, if you encounter a login screen when connecting with the screen command, try `username: root` to access the system.

Comment: I'm able to connect to the screen session (thanks for that!), but I'm not sure what to modify in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in order to set AWS credentials. I tried setting an export line in `/etc/default/docker` and `/etc/docker/profile` (as mentioned in https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19392#issuecomment-221654053), but no luck.

I think I'm going to go a different direction with this until I can move to Linux, but I appreciate the help.

Comment: @MikeOttum You need to modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` following the example available [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.10/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/), in the section *Daemon configuration file*.

For your convenience, the `daemon.json` file would look something like the following:

`{
 "storage-driver": "aufs",
 "debug": true,
 "log-driver": "awslogs",
 "log-opts": ["awslogs-region=us-east-1", "awslogs-group=myLogGroup"]
}`

However, docker restart overrides that file.  Probably you'll need to add the variables to: `/etc/init.d/docker`